# python not understanding simple math question

Tags: python, variables, math

I am making mortgage calculator, I have provided information for variables p, i, n, but get error in the equation.

```
p[i(1 + i) ^ n] / [(1 + i) ^ n – 1]
```

Comment: Beware. `^` means XOR in python. Btw, what's the error?

Comment: What's your question? Please [edit] to clarify. If you want debugging help, you need to provide a [mre] inclusing the full error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you shared is not valid python code. Here is an example of code that will accomplish what you are asking:

```
# define function:
def CalculateMortgage(p, i, n):

    # calculate numerator:
    numerator = p * (i *(1+i) ** n)

    # calculate denominator:
    denominator = ((1+i) ** n - 1)

    # calculate mortgage:
    mortgage = numerator/denominator 

    # return result:
    return mortgage


# set variables:
p = 1
i = 1
n = 1

# call function:
mortgage = CalculateMortgage(p, i, n)

# print result:
print('Your mortgage is: ' + str(mortgage))
```